# Where is log.info written?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am working on a grails 2.2.4 application and i have found code like

`log.info("info to be logged")`

but i don't know where i can fond the file that is being written or if the location for the log file can be configured somewhere.

I thought that it may be written in stackstrace.log but that does not seem correct.

I thought that it may be written in the database but i cannot find the log anywhere.

I have searched the project directory for the log and i cannot find it.

Amy help would be appreciated since i haven't found where that log is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In grails 2, logging is accomplished via log4j and can be configured per the information in the documentation here: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.2.4/guide/conf.html#logging

If you cannot access the full documentation, or want a quick reference, you basically need to add a `log4j` section to your Config.groovy file with a block like

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        appender new RollingFileAppender(
            name: "myAppender",
            maxFileSize: 1024,
            file: "/tmp/logs/myApp.log")
    }
}
```

Log4j is extremely customizable, so I wouldn't recommend just copying that verbatim and calling it complete, but instead use this as a starting point.